# WAN DS framing unit different to the layer 2 frame datagram

Tags: wan, layer2

I am doing an online course and just want to check my understanding with terminology. Do the WAN framing units such as SDH STM-n and SONET STS-n have anything to do with the layer 2 (datalink) datagram called a frame?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a difference. The STM and STS framing units are both Time Division Multiplexing protocols operating at layer 1 in the OSI networking stack. They help to arrange the data into time divided channels on the optical fibre. Exactly 24 time slots at the level 0 channel rate of DS0.

The use of the word frame in this layer 1 context appears to be an unfortunate ambiguity as it is not connected to the layer 2 'frame' datagram.

The layer 2 datalink layer in the OSI stack may use a number of protocols such as PPP over a WAN to wrap layer 3 data with headers and footers into a 'frame' datagram for transmission by lower layer 1 technology.